# How to test Google code examples?

Tags: android

I use Android Studio - How do you go about testing the official examples [such as this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectServiceDiscovery)?

I do not want to have to copy and paste all files into my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you new with android , you can test these applicavia developer mode on your device using ADT Bundle or android studios IDE for android 
for such thing you have to write down or copy paste the code into your project and then when you are done attach your device to your system and turn on developer mode and try running application on device and test this application

Comment: I have Android studio.  I would like to test the code without copying and pasting each file

Comment: so the code you are using is for eclipse so you must down the code and import in eclipse but in android studio  you must down load the code folder first and then paste it on desktop and in android studio go to file menu and import code from the desktop to android studios your complete project will be imported in the  android studio

Comment: Thank you for your help.  My only problem is I don't know how to download all the code at once :(

Comment: in your link can you see tgz button its very small but you can see , click over that and after it will be downloaded

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+archive/12634496be8d78f09755f831a3b92919af0fc31e.tar.gz